# vpnc: no response from target

Tags: ipsec, vpn

I have not be able to for a tunnel using vpnc or shrew soft to my pfsense box running IPSec. I have made sure that the correct ports are open, the user I'm trying to log in has the correct permissions (User - VPN - IPsec xauth Dialin), and my config is correct. Yet I cannot get the tunnel to come up for some reason.

nmap of the server

```
# nmap -sSU <gateway ip> -p500,4500

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-10-01 10:57 EDT
Nmap scan report for <gateway ip>
Host is up (0.017s latency).
PORT     STATE         SERVICE
500/tcp  filtered      isakmp
4500/tcp filtered      sae-urn
500/udp  open|filtered isakmp
4500/udp open|filtered nat-t-ike
```

vpnc config file being used:

```
IPSec gateway <gateway ip>
IPSec ID <username@domain>
IPSec secret [secret]
IKE Authmode psk
Xauth username <username@domain> # same as above
Xauth password [secret] #same as above
#Vendor netscreen
```

Here is a link to the debug out put of vpnc

http://pastebin.com/mTuKLYek

Basically the output of vpnc ends with

`PARSING PAYLOAD type: 00 (ISAKMP_PAYLOAD_NONE)
   PARSE_OK`

`vpnc: no response from target`

Here is a link to relevant parts of racoon.conf

http://pastebin.com/CJLyk63X

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution?